# Sails blueprint populate not working on creation?

Tags: sails.js

According to [this](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/blueprint-api/create#?create-record-while-associating-w-existing-record-rest), when creating a new record with association to some other record, the response should contain the associated record populated.

```
POST /pony
{
  "name": "Pinkie Pie",
  "pet": 1
}
```

And the response should be like

```
{
  "name": "Pinkie Pie",
  "pet": {
    "name": "Gummy",
    "id": 1
  },
  "id": 4,
  "createdAt": "2013-10-18T01:22:56.000Z",
  "updatedAt": "2013-11-26T22:54:19.951Z"
}
```

Instead, I actually get a `"pet": 1` in response.

My steps are like this:

1. `sails new test`
2. `sails generate api pony`
3. `sails generate api pet`
4. add `"name" : "string"` to both models
5. add `"pet" : { "model" : "pet" }` to pony model

Should I do anything else to get the blueprint api populate the `pet` property in response of `pony` creation or do I have to do another request just to get the pet populated?

Comment: Are you sure that pet `Gummy` id is `1` that is integer?

Comment: It's an auto-generated primary column, so I think it should be. Also, calling `GET /pony` after creation returns correctly populated record.

Comment: Alright if you are sure that `Gummy` is exist with ID `1`. See my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, `blueprint` at `create` action is not doing `populateAll` trough any new instance that created. Look at it's [source code](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/blob/v0.11.0/lib/hooks/blueprints/actions/create.js).

If you want to auto populate created content, you should override default `blueprint` at `create` action, to something like.

```
create: function(req, res){
  var Model = actionUtil.parseModel(req);

  // Create data object (monolithic combination of all parameters)
  // Omit the blacklisted params (like JSONP callback param, etc.)
  var data = actionUtil.parseValues(req);


  // Create new instance of model using data from params
  Model.create(data).exec(function created (err, newInstance) {

    // Differentiate between waterline-originated validation errors
    // and serious underlying issues. Respond with badRequest if a
    // validation error is encountered, w/ validation info.
    if (err) return res.negotiate(err);

    // If we have the pubsub hook, use the model class's publish method
    // to notify all subscribers about the created item
    if (req._sails.hooks.pubsub) {
      if (req.isSocket) {
        Model.subscribe(req, newInstance);
        Model.introduce(newInstance);
      }
      Model.publishCreate(newInstance, !req.options.mirror && req);
    }

    // Send JSONP-friendly response if it's supported
    // populate it first
    Model
      .findOne({id:newInstance.id})
      .populateAll()
      .exec(function(err, populatedInstance){
        if (err) return res.negotiate(err);

        res.created(populatedInstance);
      });
  });
}
```

Comment: Nice. Thanks a lot for this. So, the documentation is, once again, a little bit misleading.

Comment: Seems silly for an MVC framework to have this level of hassle for something so basic...

Comment: @Sebastialonso I don't know for current stage, is it already implemented on core or not, since I never use Sails anymore :p

Answer (score 1):

Andi's answer is spot on. Here's an implementation using waterline's promises

**api/blueprints/create.js**

```
'use strict';

let actionUtil = require('sails/lib/hooks/blueprints/actionUtil')

/**
 * Create Record
 *
 * post /:modelIdentity
 *
 * An API call to find and return a single model instance from the data adapter
 * using the specified criteria.  If an id was specified, just the instance with
 * that unique id will be returned.
 *
 * Optional:
 * @param {String} callback - default jsonp callback param (i.e. the name of the js function returned)
 * @param {*} * - other params will be used as `values` in the create
 */
module.exports = function createRecord (req, res) {
  var Model = actionUtil.parseModel(req);

  var data = actionUtil.parseValues(req);

  Model
    .create(_.omit(data, 'id'))
    .then(newInstance => Model.findOne(newInstance.id).populateAll())
    .then(res.created)
    .catch(res.negotiate);
}
```